# Count textarea and input using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, input, textarea

I am using the following code to count the number of required input (textboxes) on an HTML5 form, which works fine.

```
var inputTags = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
reqinputCount = 0;
for (var i=0, length = inputTags.length; i<length; i++) {
    if (inputTags[i].validity.valid == false ) {
        reqinputCount++;
    }
}
```

Now my problem is that I also have a textarea on the form and want to include that as well. 
Can you please help me out.
Thanking in advance.

Comment: How do you determine whether or not a tag is required? What is your validity attribute?

Comment: @Aiias Basic HTML5 form feature.

Comment: You can get a collection of **every** control in a form using the DOM 0 [`form.elements`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#dom-form-elements) collection, then just iterate over that.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're already relying on a feature only present in the newest versions of browsers, I'm assuming it's safe to assume you don't mind another such feature being used:

```
var inputTags = document.querySelector("input,textarea");
```

Comment: If the OP wants to delve into HTML5 and not be backward compatible (not advised but might be fun for an exercise), he should read HTML5 [§4.10 Forms](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html). In any case, I think `form.elements` would be better to get all the controls, then deal with each as required (using HTML5 properties or stock HTML 4.01 as appropriate).